# Intuitively, why is X% of Y = Y% of X?

Tags: percentages

I didn't spot this trick until I read [this](https://redd.it/7yvxw4):

> LPT: X percent of Y is equal to Y percent of X.

I know that multiplication is commutative; obviously,
 $\dfrac{X}{100}Y= X\dfrac{Y}{100}$. But this algebra doesn't betray the intuition that I feel I'm missing?  How can this be intuited?

Comment: Because both are equal to $XY$ percentage of $1$?

Comment: I think fix my intuition questions are outside the scope of SO maths

Comment: @PaulChilds We get them fairly often and don’t tend to close them, and in my opinion they are fun and mentally stimulating. I would rather see eight of these than a single here’s-a-textbook-problem-I-couldn’t-do post.

Comment: percent implies a part of number, so intuitively speaking and wlog, a small part of a large number is the large part of the small number.

Comment: I think intuition questions are one of the most valuable parts of math.stackexchange. Developing intuitive understanding is one of the main challenges of learning math, is it not. I know I have often read a proof in a textbook which seemed terribly unmotivated, only to realize a year or two later that the proof is "obvious" once you see it from the right viewpoint. Such intuition is often missing from textbooks, but thankfully you can find it on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Say,You have $$ 5\%~~of~~1000$ $$

So,here, $$x=5~~and~~y=1000$$
So,you have $$5\$~~in~~100\$$$
$$And, 50\$~~in~~1000\$ $$

Now,let's say you have $$1000\%~~ of~~5\$$$
So,this time also $$x=5~~and~~y=1000~~~[according~to~your~strategy]$$

But now notice carefully..what  is it saying?this time it is enlarging the 5$.How?

this means-
$$ by~~100\$~~we~~have~~1000\$ $$
hence,$$by~~5\$~~we~~have~~50\$ $$

Comment: Ah yes but A% B = B% A  can only work with A and B unitless value due to the % operator requiring a unitless value on the LHS

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get you.will you please clear your question? BTW,This is the way percentage is taken.it is just a operator.